# How to get dynamically passed parameters in controller's constructor before it reaches to controller function in codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, routes, codeigniter-3

I have a route called

```
$route['client-contact-edit-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).html'] = "user/user/client_contact/$1/$2";
```

URL will be like:

```
http://www.project.com/client-contact-edit-10-20.html
```

I want to have values $1 and $2 in constructor of this controller.
And I don't want to make use of uri segment as I may want to fetch 2 or more than 2 parameters.

Is there any possible solution?